# Changing the element background color on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have attached my HTML code below. I am trying to change the color of this element on click. I have a script that works on click, but the color is not changing for some reason.

```js
function myfunction() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("tag14"); // get all elements
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
        elements[i].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    }
}
```

```css
.tag14 span {
    padding: 6px 10px;
    background: #D0E8E4;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: #091747;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0 4px 8px 0;
    font-weight: 500;
    display: inline-block;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: normal;
}

.tag14 span:hover{
background:red;
}

.tag14 span:focus{
background:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="tag14" onclick="myfunction();"><span>Hello</span></div>
```

I think it's something in the function that is not operating correctly.

***Update 2***
With help, I figured out how to toggle click on and off:

```
<style>
.tag14 span {
    padding: 6px 10px;
    background: brown;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: #091747;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0 4px 8px 0;
    font-weight: 500;
    display: inline-block;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: normal;
}


.tag14 span:focus{
   background:green;
}

</style>

<script>
function myfunction() {
    
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("tag_span"); // get all elements
    
      for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
            if (elements[i].style.backgroundColor === ""){
                elements[i].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
                elements[i].style.color = "white"; 
            } else {
                elements[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
                elements[i].style.color = "black";
            }
      }
}
</script>


<div class="tag14" onclick="myfunction();"><span class="tag_span">Hello</span></div>
```

Comment: It does work actually. Could you elaborate on what you want to do? Do you want to change the background of the Div-element or the Span-element?

Comment: Is there anything in ```elements```?

Comment: @MarLMazo sure! So when I run it, and it starts out, there is like a sky blue color (#D0E8E4) - and when I click on the element, I want that sky blue to turn to regular blue and stay regular blue. But when I click it, I only see the red hover color, which obviously goes away when it's not hovered. The element remains that sky blue and doesn't change. I want to change the color of the span element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you only need to select the Span-element instead of the DIV-element.

So here I added an extra class for the span and you can select the span itself.

```js
function myfunction() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("tag_span"); // get all elements
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
        elements[i].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
        elements[i].style.color = "white"; //added this extra element so that you can see the Hello 
    }
}
```

```css
.tag14 span {
    padding: 6px 10px;
    background: #D0E8E4;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: #091747;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0 4px 8px 0;
    font-weight: 500;
    display: inline-block;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: normal;
}

.tag14 span:hover{
    background:red; /* you can add red !important so it will still work after the click event. So when you change the Span background color in JS, it will be an inline css styling that has higher priority than this one*/
}

.tag14 span:focus{
   background:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="tag14" onclick="myfunction();"><span class="tag_span">Hello</span></div>
```

But I don't recommend you putting an onclick function on a Div-element.
So better put it on the Script by adding an event listener to it. You can learn more about event-listener here [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp)

Comment: You're great! Thank you! And to reverse it if the user clicks off, would you recommend an if statement in myfunction() that goes into the current function as you wrote it above if elements[i].style.backgroundColor = "#D0E8E4", and goes into the opposite if elements[i].style.backgroundColor = "blue" ?

Comment: I'm not actually sure what you mean by clicks off. But if the user clicks again, you can revert it back. You can learn it from here on how to toggle styling or classes. [W3school tutorial on Toggle](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp)

Comment: Thank you! You're awesome. I figured out how to do it and I attached the code in Update 2 above. My last question is about the clicking itself. When I hover over the text of the element, the text cursor pops up - when I want the pointer cursor to be the only cursor shown when the user goes to click on the element. Is this possible?

Comment: @youewew this will help you about cursor [w3school Cursor](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I used it to figure it out - When I have a list of different spans, and one is clicked, it changes the color of them all. Is there a way to just change the color of the one that was clicked? I have tried specifying `elements.length`, but that just highlights the last element every time.